# Tests hang with http client connection pool issue

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

When I run my tests they hang at the same point: when I try to send a request.
I understand that there are no free connections in the pool but I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?
Code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    public class ClientTest {
private static String username = ITProperties.getInstance().getProperty("username");
private static String password = ITProperties.getInstance().getProperty("password");
private static CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
private static UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);

public static final HttpClient HTTP_CLIENT = buildHttpClientWithCredentials();

public static HttpClient buildHttpClientWithCredentials() {
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
    return HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
}

    @Test
    public void testWhenClientNotFound() throws JSONException, IOException {
        String requestBody = new RequestBody().setSum(100000L).setDay(7).toString();
        HttpPost request = RequestProvider.getPostRequest(URL, requestBody);

        HttpResponse response = HTTP_CLIENT.execute(request); //HERE EXECUTION HANGS

        assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(404);
    }

    ...
    }
```

From log:

```
2017-08-10 12:24:13,787 DEBUG | main | org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process.123 | CookieSpec selected: default 
2017-08-10 12:24:13,787 DEBUG | main | org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process.168 | Cookie [version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 00000000000000000000000000000][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: null] match [localhost:9900/path/to/my/resource] 
2017-08-10 12:24:13,787 DEBUG | main | org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache.process.77 | Auth cache not set in the context 
2017-08-10 12:24:13,787 DEBUG | main | org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection.255 | Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:9900][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20] 
2017-08-10 12:24:33,919 DEBUG | HikariPool-1 housekeeper | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.logPoolState.378 | HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=2, active=0, idle=2, waiting=0)
```

Comment: updated the code. I'm trying to check response code.

Comment: it's just URL. Like: http://localhost:9900/path/to/my/resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to close your response:

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
try {
    <...>
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Then you can configure a thread pool as described [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e393):

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new 
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(200);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost("locahost", 80);
cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), 50);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setConnectionManager(cm)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write the code to `CloseableHttpResponse`. You can use  `EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity)` call – necessary to consume the entire content of the response (entity) so that the manager can release the connection back to the pool.
Add this line after the utilization of the client response.